# Is it possible to set the 'acks' (acknowledgement) property other than in Producer configuration

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Need help in understanding the 'acks' property in Kafka which is there in the Producer Configuration.

Let's say if I missed passing 'acks' property in the producer class. Then by default Kafka considers it  'acks =0. Now suppose I need to have 'acks=all' so that it will guarantee my message delivery to Kafka broker. Is there any way I can make sure it always has' acks=all' by default all the time may be any setting in server.properties file?

I have read the Kafka documentation https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/

Answer (score 1):

With the Java client, the default value for `acks` is 1, meaning an aknowledgement is sent back to the producer once the broker has received the message, see http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs

This configuration has to be set on all producer clients. There's nothing you can do on the brokers to change that.